# NOTE: FriendlyId 4.x breaks compatibility with 3.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, refinerycms, gemfile

I create a new Refinery application and face some problems. I following to instuction on official web-site Refinery http://refinerycms.com/guides/heroku. One of this mistakes says: NOTE: FriendlyId 4.x breaks compatibility with 3.x. But I unload rails version 3.2.18. What problem is? When I open my application on heroku: We're sorry, but something went wrong.

**My Gemfile:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.18'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_log_stdout',           github: 'heroku/rails_log_stdout'
  gem 'rails3_serve_static_assets', github: 'heroku/rails3_serve_static_assets'
end

gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'

# Refinery CMS
gem 'refinerycms', '~> 2.1.0'

# Optionally, specify additional Refinery CMS Extensions here:
gem 'refinerycms-acts-as-indexed', '~> 1.0.0'
#  gem 'refinerycms-blog', '~> 2.1.0'
#  gem 'refinerycms-inquiries', '~> 2.1.0'
#  gem 'refinerycms-search', '~> 2.1.0'
#  gem 'refinerycms-page-images', '~> 2.1.0'

# The Heroku gem allows you to interface with Heroku's API
gem 'heroku'

# Fog allows you to use S3 assets (added for Heroku)
gem 'fog'

# Postgres support (added for Heroku)
gem 'pg'
```

**Terminal:**

```
ark@ark-Aspire-5750G:~/mirprirodi$ git push heroku master
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 95, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (81/81), done.
Writing objects: 100% (95/95), 35.82 KiB, done.
Total 95 (delta 15), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.6.3
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Your Gemfile lists the gem pg (>= 0) more than once.
       You should probably keep only one of them.
       While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
       Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Fetching git://github.com/heroku/rails3_serve_static_assets.git
       Fetching git://github.com/heroku/rails_log_stdout.git
       Installing multi_json 1.10.1
       Installing i18n 0.6.9
       Installing rake 10.3.2
       Installing builder 3.0.4
       Installing journey 1.0.4
       Installing erubis 2.7.0
       Installing hike 1.2.3
       Installing rack 1.4.5
       Installing tilt 1.4.1
       Installing polyglot 0.3.5
       Installing mime-types 1.25.1
       Installing arel 3.0.3
       Installing acts_as_indexed 0.8.3
       Installing addressable 2.3.6
       Installing babosa 0.3.11
       Installing tzinfo 0.3.39
       Installing coffee-script-source 1.7.0
       Installing execjs 2.2.1
       Installing thor 0.19.1
       Installing orm_adapter 0.5.0
       Installing excon 0.37.0
       Installing formatador 0.2.5
       Installing json 1.8.1
       Installing bcrypt 3.1.7
       Installing inflecto 0.0.2
       Installing ipaddress 0.8.0
       Installing net-ssh 2.9.1
       Installing mini_portile 0.6.0
       Installing netrc 0.7.7
       Using bundler 1.6.3
       Using rails3_serve_static_assets 0.0.1 from git://github.com/heroku/rails3_serve_static_assets.git (at master)
       Installing rubyzip 1.1.4
       Installing rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.2
       Using rails_log_stdout 0.0.1 from git://github.com/heroku/rails_log_stdout.git (at master)
       Installing rails_stdout_logging 0.0.3
       Installing truncate_html 0.9.2
       Installing sass 3.3.9
       Installing will_paginate 3.0.6
       Installing fog-json 1.0.0
       Installing activesupport 3.2.18
       Installing rails-i18n 0.7.4
       Installing rack-test 0.6.2
       Installing rack-cache 1.2
       Installing rack-ssl 1.3.4
       Installing warden 1.2.3
       Installing sprockets 2.2.2
       Installing dragonfly 0.9.15
       Installing treetop 1.4.15
       Installing rest-client 1.6.7
       Installing launchy 2.4.2
       Installing coffee-script 2.2.0
       Installing heroku-api 0.3.18
       Installing rdoc 3.12.2
       Installing uglifier 2.5.1
       Installing bcrypt-ruby 3.1.5
       Installing net-scp 1.2.1
       Installing rails_12factor 0.0.2
       Installing activemodel 3.2.18
       Installing mail 2.5.4
       Installing heroku 3.8.4
       Installing fog-core 1.22.0
       Installing actionpack 3.2.18
       Installing activerecord 3.2.18
       Installing activeresource 3.2.18
       Installing fog-brightbox 0.1.0
       Installing actionmailer 3.2.18
       Installing railties 3.2.18
       Installing routing-filter 0.3.1
       Installing pg 0.17.1
       Installing awesome_nested_set 2.1.6
       Installing friendly_id 4.0.10.1
       Installing globalize 3.1.0
       Installing coffee-rails 3.2.2
       Installing decorators 1.0.3
       Installing devise 2.2.8
       Installing jquery-rails 2.3.0
       Installing rails 3.2.18
       Installing sass-rails 3.2.6
       Installing seo_meta 1.4.0
       Installing refinerycms-i18n 2.1.0
       Installing refinerycms-core 2.1.2
       Installing refinerycms-dashboard 2.1.2
       Installing refinerycms-authentication 2.1.2
       Installing refinerycms-images 2.1.2
       Installing refinerycms-pages 2.1.2
       Installing refinerycms-resources 2.1.2
       Installing refinerycms-acts-as-indexed 1.0.0
       Installing refinerycms 2.1.2
       Installing nokogiri 1.6.2.1
       Installing fog 1.22.1
       Your bundle is complete!
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Post-install message from rdoc:
       Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:
       <= 1.8.6 : unsupported
       = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
       = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
       >= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!
       Post-install message from bcrypt-ruby:
       #######################################################
       The bcrypt-ruby gem has changed its name to just bcrypt.  Instead of
       installing `bcrypt-ruby`, you should install `bcrypt`.  Please update your
       dependencies accordingly.
       #######################################################
       Post-install message from heroku:
       !    The `heroku` gem has been deprecated and replaced with the Heroku Toolbelt.
       !    Download and install from: https://toolbelt.heroku.com
       !    For API access, see: https://github.com/heroku/heroku.rb
       Post-install message from friendly_id:
       NOTE: FriendlyId 4.x breaks compatibility with 3.x. If you're upgrading
       from 3.x, please see this document:
       http://rubydoc.info/github/norman/friendly_id/master/file/WhatsNew.md
       Post-install message from globalize:
       Globalize has extracted versioning support to a separate gem named
       globalize-versioning. If you are using versioning (with paper_trail
       or any other versioning gem), please add the line
       "gem 'globalize-versioning'" to your Gemfile and go to the github
       page at globalize/globalize-versioning if you encounter any problems.
       Note that the globalize-versioning gem does not delegate versions to
       the translation table, so you will have to update your syntax to
       the form: `post.translation.versions`. See the globalize-versioning
       readme for details.
       Bundle completed (31.77s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       Compiled jquery.js  (4ms)  (pid 1429)
       Compiled jquery_ujs.js  (0ms)  (pid 1429)
       Compiled application.js  (15ms)  (pid 1429)
       Compiled application.css  (0ms)  (pid 1429)
       Compiled jquery.js  (5ms)  (pid 1429)
       Compiled jquery_ujs.js  (0ms)  (pid 1429)
       Compiled application.js  (69ms)  (pid 1429)
       Compiled application.css  (0ms)  (pid 1429)
       Asset precompilation completed (18.38s)
-----> WARNINGS:
       You have not declared a Ruby version in your Gemfile.
       To set your Ruby version add this line to your Gemfile:
       ruby '2.0.0'
       # See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions for more information.

       No Procfile detected, using the default web server (webrick)
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> (none)
       Default types for Ruby  -> console, rake, web, worker

-----> Compressing... done, 27.3MB
-----> Launching... done, v6
       http://stormy-caverns-7064.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku

To git@heroku.com:stormy-caverns-7064.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
ark@ark-Aspire-5750G:~/mirprirodi$ heroku open
Opening stormy-caverns-7064... done
ark@ark-Aspire-5750G:~/mirprirodi$
```

Comment: It's talking about friendly_id version 4 breaking compatibility with friendly_id 3.  It's not about rails, version 4 will work with rails 3

Comment: No idea, what is in your log file?